# I can't get the token from URL

Tags: express

Anyone Have an idea why the token is undefined when clicking confirmation link i can't get it from the url using this code
it return {"message":"Missing token"}
language:nodejs(express) [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYD28.png)

code:

```
exports.verifying = async (req,res) => {
  const {token} =req.params
  console.log(token)
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(422).json({ 
         message: "Missing Token" 
    });
}
// Step 1 -  Verify the token from the URL
let payload = null
try {
    payload = jwt.verify(
       req.token,
       process.env.JWT_ACC_ACTIVATE
    );
} catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({err:"something went wrong"});
}
try{
    // Step 2 - Find user with matching ID
    
    if (!user) {
       return res.status(404).json({ 
          message: "User does not  exists" 
       });
    }
    // Step 3 - Update user verification status to true
    user.verified = true;
    await user.save();
    return res.status(200).json({
          message: "Account Verified"
    });
 } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json(err);
 }

 
}
```

Comment: show me your routing...

Comment: router.post('/signin', signin)

router.get("/signout", signout)
router.get('/verify/:id',verifying)
router.post('/forgotpassword',forgotpassword)    it reurn now this error msg err:"something went wrong"

Comment: With this routing you can access to just `id`of `req.param` because of `:id`, so I think you put the token in the `req.query`. So check with req.query and give me a feedbacn

Comment: i was blocked by error message which i've cretaed "something went wrong"